# Ajax get the POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having problem in getting the values from ajax.

here in this file my ajax code is http://websiteeonline.com/form-editable.js

And my form looks something like this with the firebug. http://websiteeonline.com/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-02%20at%2012.04.45%20pm.png

[image]

I use this kind of PHP code.

```
<?php include('admin-header.php'); 

    if(isset($_GET['useredit']))
    {

        $uid=$_GET['useredit'];
        $EditUserDetails=$user_details->find_by_id($uid);



        if(isset($_REQUEST['mobile']) || isset($_POST['mobile']))
        {
            echo "some value";
             $mobile=$_GET['value'];
        }

    }

?>
```

I dont know where the problem is i can not get into the "IF" loop and i want to get the "mobile" updated value so that i can update into mysql DB. Please help me. I am not getting the problem.

Thank you! (advance)

Comment: Please show the code that is making the request (not a link to a whole ball of code - just the lines that matter). Where do you define `$user_details`? Are you setting query parameters `user edit` and `mobile`? How are you passing `$mobile` back to the page making the AJAX request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pic, The POST variables are name="mobile". So your `$_REQUEST['mobile']` is wrong. Check for `isset($_POST['name'])` and then `$_POST['name'] == 'mobile'`

Comment: It worked. thank you! in my javascript file can i change this to current useredit value instead of user-edit.php?useredit=9 i dont want to make "9" specifically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by changing the value. It's the user_id right? Won't it effect your query?

Comment: No, please look at the http://websiteeonline.com/form-editable.js there you will find user-edit.php?useredit=9 so, i want to remove 9 and use the current user_id which will be dynamic and i will get from URL. You can look in the above screenshot the URL is there. which is /post.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. What you can do is make that .js file as .php and perform a db select opertion. But that would have the overhead of changing the file's name from .js to .php in every other file it's used in.

Comment: I tried but didnt work much around. Can you provide some another solution?